# Is there a way to lock Shader node In blender?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, shaders, compositing-nodes, shader-nodes

After completing the work, to customize all the nodes, we use the Tab key. Now, I'm wondering how to lock or restrict access to this shader. In other words, I want to ensure that other users can't see the nodes created using the Tab key and can only use the customized shader without access to the nodes.

Is such a feature possible in Blender? If yes, how can I achieve this? I genuinely appreciate your guidance on this matter.

Comment: *Is such a feature possible in Blender?* I doubt that is feasible natively. Blender's main philosophy is focused on openness, sharing of knowledge and customizability. There are no builtin paywalls, obfuscation methods or forms of DRM. For every possible workaround, there may be any number of counter techniques to reverse it

Comment: Hi :). You can *link* the nodegroup from a different file or scene. Depending on the Blender version, users may see the nodes, but won't accidentally change them.